# Regex get song h:m:s when h and m is optional

Tags: regex

Pattern:

```
(.*?) (?:(\d+)\:)??(?:(\d+)\:)??(\d+)
```

Input

```
song1.mp3 2:35
song2.mp3 1:2:45
song3.mp3 45
```

Replace:

```
the song "$1" is $3min and $4sec
```

Result I want

```
the song "song1.mp3" is 2min and 35sec
the song "song2.mp3" is 2min and 45sec
the song "song3.mp3" is min and 45sec
```

What happens is the minute part attempts to not happen and for some reason the leftmost nongreedy pattern (`.*?`) before space happens instead of the rightmost nongreedy pattern (`(?:(\d+)\:)??`).

That seems bizarre behavior. I tried it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which uses flash and http://regexpal.com/ which uses JS

I can fix it using `$` at the end but what if I don't want to match the end? `.*$` breaks it.

I mostly care about .NET and JS solutions.

Comment: `(.*\.\w+) ((\d+):)?(\d+):(\d+)` works in regexpal.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Patashu your comment looks like an answer - why not answer with this?

Comment: @Patashu: Thats not making minutes optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<song>[^ ]+) (?:(?:(?<h>\d+):)?(?:(?<m>\d+):))?(?<s>\d+)
```

Comment: Awesome! All I need to do is add more brackets!? I would have never thought of that.

Now I believe ?? is useless again ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work for all of your examples, replace matches of:

```
(.*?) (\d+:)?(\d+):(\d+)
```

with:

```
the song "$1" is $3min and $4sec
```

Comment: Title says h *and* m are optional... another `?` needed?

Comment: The title says that, but the examples provided in the question all have minutes provided.

Comment: Yes it does but I still would like it to be optional. I edited the example. But there is an accepted answer already